# LightOpenID - Provider - Script is stuck at "allow once","allow always","cancel"

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I have the example-mysql.php LightOpenID provider script running on a localhost virtualhost on my machine. I updated the table names and mysql_connect() parameters to work on my local machine. I also created a user in the users table.

I'm using the example.php LightOpenID consumer script to test the provider script. Everything works up until I get to "http://site1" wants access, Allow Once, Allow Always, Cancel. Pressing either of the allow buttons creates a new allowedsites row, but the page just refreshes with the buttons again. It verifies my login against the database or I would get "wrong user/pass" but never finishes the process and redirects me...

Provider script: https://gist.github.com/1072612
Consumer script: https://gist.github.com/1072613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably entered a wrong identity url.

For example, assuming the provider is on provider.example.org:

An incorrect identity would be `http://provider.example.org/example-mysql.php`. The provider would ask you for login and password, request authorization, then silently fail, because `http://provider.example.org/example-mysql.php` cannot be resolved to any login.

`http://provider.example.org/example-mysql.php?Mewp` would be a correct identity for this example.

One way to avoid this is to set `$op->select_id = true` when there's no login in the url, which would cause the server to return both claimed_id and identity to the correct url (like google does).

Comment: This was exactly it. I've set $op->select_id to true and am providing http://example.org as my identity. (provider is index.php). Now I'm having a slightly different problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658349/lightopenid-provider-issued-an-assertion-for-an-identifier-whose-discovery-info