# LightOpenID - Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery info did not match

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

This is the error I get after logging into Stack with my LightOpenID provider script.

**The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match.**

```
Assertion endpoint info: 
ClaimedIdentifier: http ://sub.mydomain.net/?cgillis 
ProviderLocalIdentifier: http ://sub.mydomain.net/?cgillis 
ProviderEndpoint: http ://sub.mydomain.net/ 
OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: 

Discovered endpoint info: [{ 
ClaimedIdentifier: http ://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select        
ProviderLocalIdentifier: http ://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select    
ProviderEndpoint: http ://sub.mydomain.net/ 
OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: http ://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server },]
```

Provider script: https://gist.github.com/1072612

I should note the provider has select_id set to true. Everything works if it's set to false.

Comment: What client do you use? Does it work with example.php from the repo? (the HTTP Auth one, not the mysql one).

Comment: It works with the example client from the repo. It does not work with StackExchange or any other website I could find that accepts OpenID.

Comment: Should note that if I set select_id to true, it works on Stack and all the others. Seems to be something wrong with the other mode.

Comment: Might be related: [Stack Overflow and Steam Community OpenIDs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55878/stack-overflow-and-steam-community-openids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that you set `select_id = true` for the identity urls. If you set it to false for only the urls returned by checkid(), it will work as expected.

See __construct() in `example.php` from the repository for an example on how can this problem be solved.

You should also see the [Provider wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/wiki/Provider) and a related [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/issues/detail?id=43)